# Create tree using multithreading and recursion

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, c#-4.0, ektron

This question is specifically related creating a tree using multithreading and recursion. 
I have got the code running that will create the tree using recursion but the time required to create that tree is more than I want to spend.

The reason for the slowness of that is because I am calling TaxonomyManager in Ektron CMS which takes a little bit to return and all the calls add up quickly. I was wondering if there is a way to create a tree using multithreading.

(I don't have the code at present with me but I will add that code as soon as I get access to that code).

If I go this route what the chances of me corrupting the tree as the tree is one root node and multithreading is going to add those nodes to that node at some point.

Thanks for any input anyone may have.

Edit: Added code. TaxonomyNodes is my class doesn't have a lot of properties. Has Id,Name,Description, Path (Stores the path in similar way as Ektron), HasChildren flag, ParentId, and public List Children.

```
public List<TaxonomyNodes> CreateTree()
    {
        try
        {

            TaxonomyManager tManager = new TaxonomyManager();
            TaxonomyCriteria criteria = new TaxonomyCriteria();
            criteria.AddFilter(TaxonomyProperty.ParentId, CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, 0);
            criteria.OrderByDirection = EkEnumeration.OrderByDirection.Ascending;
            criteria.OrderByField = TaxonomyProperty.Id;

            List<TaxonomyData> tDataList = tManager.GetList(criteria);

            int index = 0;
            if (tDataList != null)
            {
                foreach (TaxonomyData item in tDataList)
                {
                    if (item.Name != "Companies" && item.Name != "Content Information Centers")
                        root.Insert(index++, new TaxonomyNodes() { ParentId = 0, TaxonomyId = item.Id, TaxonomyDescription = item.Description, TaxonomyName = item.Name, TaxonomyPath = item.Path, HasChildren = item.HasChildren, Children = new List<TaxonomyNodes>() });
                }
            }
            index = 0;
            foreach (TaxonomyNodes itemT in root)
            {
                itemT.Children = CreateNodes(itemT.TaxonomyId, itemT);
            }

            return root;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private List<TaxonomyNodes> CreateNodes(long taxonomyId, TaxonomyNodes itemToAddTo)
    {
        try
        {
            TaxonomyManager tManager = new TaxonomyManager();
            TaxonomyCriteria criteria = new TaxonomyCriteria();
            criteria.AddFilter(TaxonomyProperty.ParentId, CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, taxonomyId);
            criteria.OrderByDirection = EkEnumeration.OrderByDirection.Ascending;
            criteria.OrderByField = TaxonomyProperty.Id;

            List<TaxonomyData> tDataList = tManager.GetList(criteria);

            List<TaxonomyNodes> node = new List<TaxonomyNodes>();
            if (tDataList != null)
            {
                foreach (TaxonomyData item in tDataList)
                {

                    node.Add(new TaxonomyNodes() { ParentId = taxonomyId, Children = null, TaxonomyId = item.Id, TaxonomyDescription = item.Description, TaxonomyName = item.Name, TaxonomyPath = item.Path, HasChildren = item.HasChildren });

                    itemToAddTo.Children = node;
                    if (item.HasChildren)
                    {
                        CreateNodes(item.Id, node[node.Count - 1]);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return node;
                    }
                }
            }

            return node;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you "call TaxonomyManager"? (I did not downvote - this is a good question, I think - especially if you add the code later)

Comment: Please read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @G.Stoynev I am not sure if you are aware of Ektron CMS but they have a framework and that contains a class that will give info about the taxonomy. I am sorry if I assumed you don't know about Ektron and if you do.

TaxonomyManager m = new TaxonomyManager();
List<TaxonomyData> td = m.GetList(<criteria that will fetch the list>);

Comment: I don't - what I am interested in is the method from c# / asp.net perspective? Is it something locally installed and referenced? Or web services? Or another method of communication? EDIT: I see you edited your comment to provide more info - so this is a local reference inside your project.

Comment: @sh1rts I am not sure which point you are referring to in the how to ask. If I am unclear about something please feel free to let me know so I can expand. As I mentioned in my question I will be posting the code so make it easier to understand on what I have completed and what I really want more.

Comment: @G.Stoynev Yes this is a local reference. I will try to simplify and not keep it CMS specific so that everyone can understand it.

Comment: Do you know what slows the CMS? It would influence the solution. For example, if it's disk I/O multithreading will not necessarily improve the times.

Comment: @G.Stoynev -- This CMS was developed to make it as generic as possible  to let most users customize the system just like wordpress. 
My guess so far as has been that they have a lot of complex queries on the SQL SERVER end. I would have asked DBA to take a look at it but with every release or update we will have implement those changes will not stick and going through the process of remembering and applying those changes may be cumbersome.

Comment: Subrato - approximately how many nodes, levels, etc? Taxonomy tends to perform pretty well in most circumstances. Also, have you tried using GetTree()? It returns the hierarchical structure in a single call rather than forcing the need to code recursion. It would also help if you posted the code you've tried.

Comment: @egandalf I have 8 root level nodes, first root level node has 18 nodes, which in turn has children. All put together first root node has 107 nodes, 2nd root level has only 13 nodes, 3rd has 51 nodes (32 at first level and few have children), 4th has 15 nodes, 5th has 54 nodes. Rest of them aren't that much. All put together I have about 251 nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than get into multithreading, which, though it may work, is not officially supported by Ektron's APIs and may present other challenges, I would recommend some form of caching or other storage for the data that does not require recursive DB calls.

Options:

1 - Ektron's Taxonomy APIs do include a GetTree method, which can pull the entire tree, up to a specified number of levels, and child items in a single API call rather than recursively. This may perform better and would be easily cached.

2 - Ektron provides API-level caching that can be readily enabled in the web.config by changing

```
<framework defaultContainer="Default" childContainer="BusinessObjects" />
```

To:

```
<framework defaultContainer="Cache" childContainer="BusinessObjects" />
```

3 - Use an eSync Strategy which will output the data you need (better to use your own streamlined objects than to store Ektron's with all the extra data) to something like an XML file. See this sample, http://developer.ektron.com/Templates/CodeLibraryDetail.aspx?id=1989&blogid=116, which I wrote to do this very thing. It hooks into the DB sync complete event and triggers a console application which writes the entire Taxonomy structure out to an XML file.